# LibGDX blinking

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I've used the LibGDX UI Setup to start a project.

The only thing I have in the implements ApplicationListener is:

```
public void create() {      
        setScreen(new LoadingScreen(this));
}
```

This is supposed to fire the LoadingScreen and it does since I have a print in its constructor and it does show. I have a print in the render method and it's only shown once and I understand this should be printed a lot of times since the render method is called every short period of time.

Here's what I have in the render() method (apart from the print):

```
OpenGL.glClearColor(1, 0.5f, 1, 1);
OpenGL.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Where `OpenGL = Gdx.graphics.getGL10();`

As I said I think render is only called once and what I see in the screen when I execute the desktop main is an image blinking from pink to black and bars going from top to bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case it It helps someone.

The problem was solved by adding to the render method in the Game extending class this:

```
    public void render() {  
    super.render();
}
```

Now it does not blink and each screen's render is called over and over as it is supposed to happen.