# Double buffering and libgdx

Tags: java, buffer, libgdx

I have a very simple application in libgdx. It currently is supposed to cover half of the screen with pink texture. And it does that, the texture however is blinking. Basing on my own understanding of subject, as well as this thread:
[LibGDX blinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475422/libgdx-blinking)
I need to enable double buffering. Or alternatively, write to my buffer. The thing is, either I am inept with google or it's very difficult to find any information how to manipulate buffers in libgdx. If someone could provide me with resources, explaining how to manipulate buffers, and how to create one, how to swap them with current display etc. I would be very grateful.

EDIT:
After searching the web some more, I found post on badlogic forum, claiming that libgdx has double buffering set by default. The question is, how does it work? When are the buffers swapped?

Answer (score 2):

Libgdx has double buffering enabled by default (its really part of the underlying OpenGL infrastructure, not Libgdx).  I don't think Libgdx exposes any controls over double buffering.  There are some controls to disable vsync which might create some tearing, but are unlikely to be related.

The more likely way to get this behavior is if, somehow, your `render` method is only invoked once.  This will draw into one buffer.  Then, assuming `render` has become a no-op, nothing is drawn into the other buffer, they're switched, nothing is drawn into the original buffer, they're switched, etc.  This can lead to the blinking behavior you're seeing.

If that guess doesn't cover it you'll have to provide more details.  Which platform are you running on?  Are you running a stable version of Libgdx or one of the nightly builds?  How are you setting up the libgdx app configuration?  What does your `render` method actually look like?