# LibGDX not rendering properly (Mac)

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx

I am trying to learn libGdx right now. However, I ran into a very VERY weird problem. After a bit of googling I am starting to think I'm the only one. Basically, whenever I run the application it starts rapidly flashing random images onto the screen

Here is an example:
[image: The output]

What is odd is that it also does that when the render method does nothing. I've tried removing all the code from it and still get the same output.

Here is what happens in the render method:

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
batch.begin();
font.draw(batch, "playing", 100, 100);
//The line that I used to test if the code is called
System.out.println("OUTPUT");
batch.end();
```

Another odd thing is that Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() always returns 0 for me.

Comment: Show some more code please. Maybe your whole screen setup or at least the whole render method.

Comment: @noone This is literally the whole content of the render method. And as I said, even if it is empty it still does that

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I fixed the issue by adding these 2 lines to the render method

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: In case you are still wondering why it actaully happened: my very first thought was "dual buffering". A quick search lead me to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987887/double-buffering-and-libgdx, which confirms "libgdx enables double  buffering by default".